# HTML - Extra space after the row in a table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am getting an extra space in each row where the data is displayed. I want to remove this, tried many ways however the space still remains after each row.

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
<table width="100%" border="0"id="slData" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-condensed dataTable" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><div align="left">Equipment </div></th>
      <th><div align="left">Quantity</div></th>
      <th><div align="left">Unit Cost</div></th>
      <th><div align="left">Equipment </div></th>
      <th><div align="left">Quantity</div></th>
      <th><div align="left">Unit Cost</div></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle">Desktop </td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="typemachin[]" value="desktop" />
      <input type="text" name="nummachine[]" style="width:50px;" value="0"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price[]"  value="0.00"style="width:50px;"/></td>
    <td>Server</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="typemachin[]" value="Server" />
      <input type="text" name="nummachine[]" style="width:50px;" value="0"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price[]"  value="0.00"style="width:50px;"/></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laptop</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="typemachin[]" value="Laptop" />
      <input type="text" name="nummachine[]" style="width:50px;" value="0"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price[]"  value="0.00"style="width:50px;"/></td>
    <td>Network</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="typemachin[]" value="Network" />
      <input type="text" name="nummachine[]" style="width:50px;" value="0"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price[]"  value="0.00"style="width:50px;"/></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Scanner/Imaging Device</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="typemachin[]" value="Scanner/Imaging Device" />
      <input type="text" name="nummachine[]" style="width:50px;" value="0"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price[]"  value="0.00"style="width:50px;"/></td>
    <td>Printer</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="typemachin[]" value="Printer" />
      <input type="text" name="nummachine[]" style="width:50px;" value="0"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price[]"  value="0.00"style="width:50px;"/></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Please add a fiddle :)

Comment: We'll need your CSS and possibly your PHP.

Comment: Paste here url, or CSS style for the table... or try debug it in browser debuger. In the debugger you can try turn off or on or replace some styles.

Comment: what space is the issue?

Comment: There are some possible things which could have caused this: a bottom margin in the textboxes, a height value defined in the `td` elements, etc. So please paste the relevant code or create a fiddle so we can better help you with your problem.

Comment: we can't help you without your css definations. please tell us about them. there are many things can cause this ;)

Comment: Either your input fields have padding (which is what I'm betting on) or your `<td>`'s have padding, which is likely but it's not looking like it. Try adding `style="padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;"` on one of your `<td>`'s and one of your input's to see what happens!